# Why is PGmc *hanhaną cogante with *hōkaz, variant of *hakô (“hook”) and not with *hanhuz?

Tags: etymology

Why is PGmc *hanhaną cogante with *hōkaz, variant of *hakô (“hook”) and not with *hanhuz?

Comment: We don't usually like questions about specific etymologies here. But in regards to your question, I was under the impression that *hanhaną and *hōkaz are not cognates, as they come from different PIE roots, *ḱenk- and *keg- respectively.

Comment: @ⰲⱁⰴⰰ Why are not PGmc *hanhaną and *hanhuz cognate?

Comment: @ⰲⱁⰴⰰ You should see Orel - A handbook of germanic etymology